# how-to configure a bgp-ls peer

Tags: opendaylight, bgp

I have brought up an Opendaylight instance in order to establish a BGP-LS session with our network and get topology information.
So, the objective is to configure 1 peering with a router and get node, link,network information.

I have concluded that the documentation is more accurate over here: https://github.com/opendaylight/docs/blob/master/docs/user-guide/bgpcep-guide/bgp/bgp-user-guide-linkstate-family.rst

I have done this step https://github.com/opendaylight/docs/blob/master/docs/user-guide/bgpcep-guide/bgp/bgp-user-guide-running-bgp.rst and works.

Unfortunately, there are **no** such files like it is described here https://github.com/opendaylight/docs/blob/stable/lithium/manuals/user-guide/src/main/asciidoc/bgpcep/odl-bgpcep-bgp-all-user.adoc
Meaning, I cannot locate `31-bgp.xml` and `41-bgp-example.xml`

I would like to ask if there are or can be derived somehow `.xml` files that describe fully all the parameters available, so that I can configure OpenDaylight by using these `.xml` files.

The examples mentioned in the first link are targeting a few specific parameters, and it is not about a nearly complete example.

Could you please advise how to:

- get the necessary bgp-ls configuration `.xml` files that fully
  configure ODL as BGP speaker and a peering ?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These files has been removed as a part of task [BGPCEP-685](https://jira.opendaylight.org/browse/BGPCEP-685).

You can still find them in previous release like [here](https://github.com/opendaylight/bgpcep/tree/release/nitrogen-sr1/bgp/controller-config/src/main/resources/initial) or [here](https://github.com/opendaylight/bgpcep/tree/release/lithium/bgp/controller-config/src/main/resources/initial)

There is also [wiki about configuring BGP peer](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/BGP_LS_PCEP:User_Guide#BGP_Peer).

Comment: thanks a lot @rkosegi for the reply. over here https://github.com/opendaylight/docs/blob/master/docs/user-guide/bgpcep-guide/bgp/bgp-user-guide-running-bgp.rst it says that "The BGP plugin contains a default configuration, which is applied after the feature starts up." do you know perhaps how can I see that ?